# login with facebook: django-allauth

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth to implement login with fb and google. It was working perfectly fine on my windows development machine. But when i shifted to the server(ubuntu 14.04 with apache2), I am facing this problem. I changed the app details on both facebook and google and have updated the databases as required with id and secret values of app and login with google is working fine from there.

But in login with facebook option, when i click on it, no popup opens as it used to happen during development.

I am not sure what the problem is. I can't find no logs in apache2 error logs also.

What could be the possible problem and how could i solve it or even know the details of what is happening.

Comment: Check your network requests. The (Facebook or Google) server responses may give you some information.

Comment: Where can i find it, please elaborate a little

Comment: Easiest way is to use Chrome developer tools - there's a network tab there that lists all your requests + responses. (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be having a problem loading the static file `fbconnect.js`, which by default is located in the directory `allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/static/facebook/js`.

If you have stated your static path in the `settings.py` at a different location, you'll have to either alter the settings or copy the file to the appropriate path specified by your static variable. :)

Comment: Yes you are right, i add facebook.js manually to my static folder and then its work like magic Thank you